# How can I clear output of a query in pgAdmin III?

Tags: pgadmin

I wonder whether I can clear the output of a query in pgAdmin III (aside from running another query).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to be an interesting "lapse", if not bug, in the (normally excellent) pgAdmin3 software.

I double checked and it is is not possible to do what you want on Windows. Update, nor is it possible on Linux. Maybe a feature request? Though, at least the behaviour is consistent: ;-)

With respect to a feature request - it appears that the list is indeed the recommended method of submission. If you provide a link here, I can update with either the Linux or Windows behaviour - whichever you may not have.