# How can I edit the content of a table in the data output of a query in pgAdmin III?

Tags: pgadmin

I wonder whether I can edit the content of table in the data output of a query in pgAdmin III? The query is a `select * from [...]`. MySQL Workbench allows users to edit the content of table in the data output of a query, but I fail to see the same option in pgAdmin III.

Comment: Again, Franck, you have come up with a lacuna in the pgAdmin3 tool. This one is, I would argue, more serious than the last one. Perhaps another feature request? Again, I could double check on Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Vérace  Thanks again, you are welcome to post the comment as an answer.

Comment: You can edit data in pgAdmin III but not in the query output window. Right click table > View data. Table needs a primary key.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Thanks, that's how I do it indeed. I was hoping one could directly edit a table through a query output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agan, Franck, you have discovered [another](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133445/how-can-i-clear-output-of-a-query-in-pgadmin-iii) (serious this time) lacuna in the pgAdmin3 tool. Perhaps you can also put in a feature request for this also.

I tested it on Windows and Linux. If you provide a link here to any feature request, I would only be too glad to put in a "me too" on the wish list (same goes for the other one).

If data is editable, then the user should be allowed to edit the data in a grid like that.